# extend() not producing a list

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a list of strings and a dataframe containing strings. Imagine the scenario:

```
A = ['the', 'a', 'with', 'from', 'on']
```

and a dataframe:

```
df = {'col1':['string', 'string'], 'col2':['the man from a town', 'the man on a bus']}
```

I am trying to now create a new column in my data_frame that would present values in column 2 of my data_frame which are in my list A (in this case: the, from, a)

What I wrote was this:

```
def words_in_A(row): 
     res=[]
     for item in A:
          if item in row:
              res.extend(item) 
              return res

df[col3] = df[col2].apply(lambda x: words_in_A(x))
```

I would expect the output to be a list with multiple values:

```
col 1          col2                   col3
string         the man from a town    'the', 'from', 'a'
string         the man on a bus       'the', 'on', 'a'
```

But the function just returns the last item ('a') rather than a list. I am not sure why this use of extend() isn't producing a list for me. Please help!

Comment: Your ‘return’ will return the first item that the ‘if’ identifies. Did you mean to have different indentation?

Comment: first of all avoid using `list` as a variable name, it is a reserved word

Comment: What is you *expected* output. Note, `col3` *does* contain a list, but it's just the list produced by `.extend`ing an empty list with the first item from `A` that is in each row...

Comment: @RichieV (btw I’ve been told it’s a built-in)

Comment: @RichieV well, it isn't *reserved* or else you couldn't use it, by definition, but good advice anyway

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga good clarification, thks

Comment: Sorry--shouldn't have used list. @juanpa.arrivillaga col3 is my desired output but the actual output I am getting is not a list, just the last item in the string that matches with a word in the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code just needed a little indentation adjustment and use `append` instead of `extend`. If you extend then the string `'the'` will be taken as a list and each letter will be appended to the collecting list.

```
def words_in_A(row): 
    lst = []
    for item in A:
        if item in row:
            lst.append(item) 
    return lst
```

I honestly though that a list comprehension and even Shubham's answer with regex would be faster than `apply`, but I stand corrected. Here's the timings with your dataframe but with 20,000 rows instead of 2.

```
with apply 0.078s
with list comp 0.076s
with regex 0.168s
with regex, no join 0.141s
```

And the testing code

```
from time import time

t0 = time()
df['col3'] = df['col2'].apply(words_in_A)
print('with apply', f'{time() - t0:.3f}s')

t0 = time()
df['col3'] = [[item for item in A if item in row] for row in df.col2]
print('with list comp', f'{time() - t0:.3f}s')

t0 = time()
pat = rf"(?i)\b(?:{'|'.join(A)})\b"
df['col3'] = df['col2'].str.findall(pat).str.join(', ')
print('with regex', f'{time() - t0:.3f}s')

t0 = time()
pat = rf"(?i)\b(?:{'|'.join(A)})\b"
df['col3'] = df['col2'].str.findall(pat)
print('with regex, no join', f'{time() - t0:.3f}s')
```

Output

```
         col1                 col2          col3
0      string  the man from a town  the, from, a
1      string    a person on a bus      a, on, a
2      string  the man from a town  the, from, a
3      string    a person on a bus      a, on, a
4      string  the man from a town  the, from, a
...       ...                  ...           ...
19995  string    a person on a bus      a, on, a
19996  string  the man from a town  the, from, a
19997  string    a person on a bus      a, on, a
19998  string  the man from a town  the, from, a
19999  string    a person on a bus      a, on, a

[20000 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Nice just wanted to point you out i am using a extra step `.join`, so i think that is taking time could you please test without `.str.join`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma it seems the `findall` call is the most expensive, who would've thought, with regex being so fast normally

Comment: that's interesting, thanks for testing richie :) +1

Comment: Thank you both ---I hadn't realised how important the indent for return was. Thank you both!

Answer (score 2):

**extend()**: Iterates over its argument and adding each element to the list and extending the list.

So `x.extend("one")` will result in ['o','n','e'] what you instead need is `x.append` which appends `one` to the end of list `x`.

Also you are populating list called `res` so you have to return it after you are done doing operations on it.

```
A = ['the', 'a', 'with', 'from', 'on']
df = {'col1':['string', 'string'], 'col2':['the man from a town', 'a person on a bus']}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

def words_in_A(row): 
  res=[]
  for item in A:
    if item in row:
      res.append(item) 
  return res

df['col3'] = df['col2'].apply(lambda x: words_in_A(x))
print (df)
```

Output:

```
     col1                 col2            col3
0  string  the man from a town  [the, a, from]
1  string    a person on a bus         [a, on]
```

Pythonic:

```
df['col3'] = df['col2'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x.split()).intersection(A)))
```

Comment: That's a good point -- I had used extend([item]) to escape that issue. Is append otherwise preferable?

Comment: Yes append is preferred here since `[item]` creates a list of single item and extend the has to iterate this list.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with a regex `pattern` to find all the matching values from list `A` then use [`Series.str.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
pat = rf"(?i)\b(?:{'|'.join(A)})\b"
df['col3'] = df['col2'].str.findall(pat).str.join(', ')
```

Result:

```
     col1                 col2          col3
0  string  the man from a town  the, from, a
1  string     the man on a bus    the, on, a
```

Comment: This worked beautifully--but just for my own sanity, what exactly was wrong with my function above?

Comment: No need to use `apply` here but if you want to then I think something [`like this`](https://repl.it/repls/SadAuthorizedTests) should work..